# Are the words "yet" and "still" synonymous in the sense of "despite"?

Tags: difference

Are the words "yet" and "still" totally synonymous in the following sentence?

> The team was unprepared, **yet**/**still** it managed to pull it off.

Answer (score 1):

It is in the form of your example.

> X, still/yet Y = Despite {change X to noun phrase}, Y.
>
> Despite the team being unprepared, they managed to pull it off.

Keep in mind that *yet* and *still* have additional meanings that *despite* doesn't have, so you can't freely substitute *despite* for *yet* or *still* in many other cases.

Comment: So are they totally synonymous in my sentence? I mean "yet" and "still"

Comment: @DmytroO'Hope This is a great answer. I think the takeaway is, yes, you can substitute "despite" for "yet/still" but the sentence will have to be rephrased. So, you can't replace "yet/still" in your exact sentence with "despite".

Comment: We can also say *"Despite the fact that the team was unprepared, they ..."* or *"Despite being unprepared, the team managed to ..."*.